# Ruby combine elements in hash

Tags: ruby, join, hash, element

I have a has that looks like this:

```
data = {abc -> [[date1, val1], [date2,val2]], def -> [[date1,val3], [date2,val4]]}
```

I want to join the abc and def elements so it's like this:

```
data = {join -> [[date1, val1+val3], [date2, val2+val4]] }
```

How do I go about this. Note that there are other elements in the hash that should not be modified.

Comment: could you write valid Ruby code so people can test directly? (input and expected output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `abc`, `def`, and `join` are actually Symbols.

```
a = Hash[data.delete(:abc)]  # extract data[:abc] and convert it to a Hash ("a")
b = Hash[data.delete(:def)]  # extract data[:def] and convert it to a Hash ("b")
data[:join] = a.map do |k,v| # iterate over one of the extracted Hashes
  [k, v + (b[k] || 0)]       # for each key, return a 2-item array with the key,
end                          #   and the sum of the values from "a" and "b"
```

Comment: Thankyou, can you explain what [k, v + (b[k] || 0)] does please?