# How to consolidate three ruby hashes into one, adding the values for common keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

How do I take three hashes and join them into one hash so that in cases where the keys are common, it adds the values, and in cases where the keys are unique, it just adds the key/value pair to the final joined hash?  Something like this:

```
r1 = { "Flour"  => 500, "Cheese"    => 1500, "Tomato Sauce" => 700 }
r2 = { "Bread"  => 300, "Cheese"    => 600,  "Butter"       => 450 }
r3 = { "Cheese" => 900, "Tortillas" => 250,  "Flour"        => 350 }
```

I tried `.merge`, but it doesn't seem to add the values of common keys...at least the way I'm doing it without a block.  I also tried this:
[Ruby combine hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897616/ruby-combine-hashes)

So, maybe it's possible with a block???  It's how to consolidate three hashes into one, adding the ones that overlap, ending with something like this:

```
r_total = { "Flour" => 850, "Cheese" => 3000, "Tomato Sauce" => 700, 
            "Bread" => 300, "Butter" => 450,  "Tortillas"    => 250 }
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" along with the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your attempt to solve this, either by the pages you searched and why they didn't help, or a code example demonstrating why it doesn't work, along with the minimum input and output that go along with the code. Without that it looks like you want us to write the solution for you, which isn't how SO works. At a minimum you can search SO, which has multiple examples of how to do this.

Comment: I tried this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897616/ruby-combine-hashes)
and this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946785/ruby-combining-hashes-in-an-array-based-on-one-hash-value)
and this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994297/ruby-combine-elements-in-hash)
and this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172821/complex-ruby-array-of-hashes-combine)
and others...but none of them answered the question that I couldn't figure out how to do myself.
As of now, there are two answers that do it perfectly and are unlike anything else I found on SO.

Comment: Please edit your question and move the "links" into the body of the question where it's easy for everyone to read them without having to read every comment. It's important to understand that a question you ask is to help others in the future in addition to helping you now. That's why we're so picky about what's in the question.

Comment: I understand wanting the question and answers to be helpful to others in the future, so I guess I'm confused how including links to questions/answers that do something other than what the title of THIS question states would accomplish that?  The title is pretty specific and the answers (two so far) answer it perfectly and concisely.  Anyhow, being new to the site, I'll put in one of the links as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could that using `reduce` + `merge`:

```
   [r1, r2, r3].reduce({}){ |memo, obj| memo.merge(obj) { |key, old, new| old + new } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a hash with a default value of 0, then iterate through each element and add up the value.

```
r_total = Hash.new(0)
[r1, r2, r3].each do |hash|
    hash.each do |k, v|
        r_total[k] += v
    end
end
r_total
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go, but suggest `[r1, r2, r3].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, r_total|...`, which returns the desired hash. If your code is packaged in a method, you need `r_total` as the last line.